# Triggering a Click on a Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a button that looks like the below:

[image: like button]

As you can see in the image there is a black border around the `<a>` aspect of the button. I added the black border. The click events are not doing anything however.

Here is my code:

```
$('.vbseo_like_link').each(function(){
    $(this).click();
    $(this).css("border", "5px solid black");
});
```

At the moment, when these are clicked there should be a Javascript `alert` that pops up along with the button becoming faded. This works when I manually click on it, however using `click()` does not seem to work.

Did I do something incorrect?

Comment: try `this.click();` if it's not working, would be better if you re-create your problem in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: try to put it in a `$(document).ready` function

Comment: @أنيسبوهاشمThis is a Chrome extension that is running at document_end, that should not be needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your manual click works, you can try `this.click()`.

- `this.click()` calls the DOM method click().
- `$(this).click()` is more complicated (trigger jQuery click event). It does the same as `$("#id").trigger("click")`.

Comment: This worked (no pun intended). Thank you. What is the difference between the `this` and `$(this)`. I assumed $(this) was the selector.

Comment: They trigger two different functions. `this` calls this: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-2651361 (native DOM function). `$(this)` utilize jQuery wrapper for click function (http://api.jquery.com/click/). You may wish to peruse `click` implementation in jQuery source code for more details.

Comment: Why is it that `$(this)` is not working then? Should it not still simulate a click on an element just like the native DOM function?

Answer (score 1):

$(this) is for the jquery selector, but your click is within each. I think Givi is right. Try this.click()